# Why is $||f||_2\leq\sqrt{2}||f||_{\infty}$?

Tags: real-analysis

In my Real Analysis book, in the section on Fourier Series, the author casually mentions that $||f||_2\leq\sqrt{2}||f||_{\infty}$ where $f\in C^{2\pi}$, the space of continuous, $2\pi$ periodic functions. Maybe I'm missing something obvious, but I'm not seeing why this is apparent.

Not really sure where to start on this one, so all I have is the definitions of $||f||_2$ and $||f||_{\infty}$:

$||f||_2=\left(\dfrac{1}{\pi}\displaystyle\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}[f(x)]^2\right)^{1/2}$

$||f||_{\infty}=\displaystyle\max_{x\in[-\pi,\pi]}|f(x)|$

Any hints would be welcomed. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} |f|^2\leqslant \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} M^2$$

Where $M$ is $\lVert f\rVert_\infty$, agreed?

Comment: Yeah. I must be really tired. Thanks.